# if condition tag is not working properly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In **demo.html**

```
<form method="post">
   {{ form1.as_p }}
</form>
<table class="table table-hover" style="width:80%;">
      <tr>
            <th>Test Case</th>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>Coverage </th>
        </tr>

        {% for key, value in d.items %}
           <tr>
               <th>{{ key }} </th>
           </tr>

            {% for k,v in value.items%}
                {% if forloop.counter <= count1 %}
                 <tr>
                      <td>   </td>
                      <td>{{ k }}</td>
                      <td>{{ v }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}


    </table>
```

In **views.py**

```
class home_changetesting(TemplateView):
template_name = 'demo.html'

def get(self, request):

    form1 = SortForm()

    return render(request,self.template_name, {'form1':form1})



def post(self, request):

    form1 = SortForm(request.POST)  
    count1=int

    if form1.is_valid():     
        count1= request.POST.get('sort')
        print(count1)
     args ={'form1':form1,'count1':count1}

    return render(request,self.template_name, args)
```

In **forms.py**

```
class SortForm(forms.Form):

sort = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1, 11)], required=False,widget=forms.Select())
```

if condition works only when I declare as **`{% if forloop.counter <= 2 %}`** Instead if I use variable as above mentioned code it does not work. Please to help me out what is the error in above code.

As if use `{{ count1 }}` the value is printing correctly.

Comment: try {% if forloop.counter <= count1|add:"0" %}

Comment: Its working fine now after using {% if forloop.counter <= count1|add:"0" %} :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
args ={'form1':form1,'count1':int(count1)}
```

use this

as you are taking input,those always comes as a `string`, thus you need to convert it to `int` before comparing with a `number` in `template`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably passing the `count1` as string into the template. To compare it, you need to cast it into an int in your view or use the add filter:

```
{% if forloop.counter <= count1|add:"0" %}
```